# Chow group over function field and algebraic equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups, limits-and-colimits

It is known that for smooth projective varieties $X,Y$ over $k=\bar k,$ $$CH^d(X_{k(Y)})=\varinjlim_{U\subset Y\ open}CH^d(X\times_k U)$$
I was wondering whether there was such an equality with algebraic equivalence (instead of rational equivalence).

Comment: If you assume this equality then you can easily run into a certain contradiction. I will try to recall this argument here if nobody else would give an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is false: see Remark 2.3.9 2)
[here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.4902.pdf).

(Appeared in AKT 1 (2016), 379-440.)